# Getting text after tag using regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm new in regular expressions. I have a string as code bellow. I want to get the text after all the `div` tags end.

```
<div class="bbcode_container">
  <div class="bbcode_quote">
    <div class="quote_container">
      <div class="bbcode_quote_container">
      </div>
      <div class="bbcode_postedby">
        <img border="0" src="http://www.webketoan.vn/forum/images/misc/quote_icon.png" alt="Click here to enlarge" onclick="window.open(this.src)" style="max-width: 700px; cursor: pointer;" title="Click here to enlarge"> Nguyên văn bởi <strong>namphong13</strong>
        <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.webketoan.vn/forum/f94/ket-qua-thi-cong-chuc-thue-126218-post842693.html#post842693"><img border="0" src="http://www.webketoan.vn/forum/images/buttons/viewpost-right.png" class="inlineimg" alt="Click here to enlarge" onclick="window.open(this.src)" style="max-width: 700px; cursor: pointer;" title="Click here to enlarge"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="message">Can you help me?<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If you need the exact text, shouldnt you just be doing a string search instead of regex?

Comment: I think we need remove html code by regular expression

Comment: you mean you want to get the text after all the div tags end?

Comment: please check the second variant from my answer

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: yes. let me check

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to see if there is the text

> Thanks for support

in your page?

Then your regex would look like:

```
match = html_string[/.+Thanks for support/]
```

If the `match` variable is not nil, then you have that text in your `html_string` variable

- If you want to catch all the text after the last closed `div`, then you could:

  `html_string =~ /.*\<\/div\>\n([a-zA-Z\s]*)$/`

  `puts $1`

Comment: try with the new regular expression I put

Answer (score 1):

You should use an HTML parser like [Nokogiri](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/) for this.

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(my_file)
# remove all the div tags
page.search('div').remove
string = page.text
```

Comment: yea. thanks. I only want to get the text after all the div tags end. I don't want get all text.

Comment: `page.search('div').remove` removes all the divs, leaving just the text you want.

Comment: with your code it will show: Can you help me?   Thanks for support. But I only want show: Thanks for support

Comment: That's incorrect. "Can you help me?" is inside a div, so it will be removed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to remove every character that occurs before the (case-insensitive) string "</div>":

```
input = 'a</div>b</DIV>c'
output = input.gsub(/.*<\/div>/i,'')    # => "c"
```